# ¿Como crear un ListView en WPF con agrupadores y contador de elementos en cada grupo?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Basandome en [este tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/) he creado un ListView con diferentes agrupadores.

Pero necesito mostrar la cantidad de elementos dentro de cada grupo y la descripción de cada uno, no tengo permitido usar la palabra genérica "Elemento(s)" en los grupos, tiene que ser más personalizada.

Por ejemplo:

```
Primer Grupo  (2 Segundos Grupos)
      Segundo Grupo  (1 Tercer Grupo)
          Tercer Grupo 3  (2 Elementos)
              Elemento 1
              Elemento 2
      Segundo Grupo  (2 Terceros Grupos)
          Tercer Grupo  (3 Elementos)
              Elemento 1
              Elemento 2
              Elemento 3
          Tercer Grupo  (1 Elementos)
              Elemento 1
```

El tutorial antes mencionado utiliza el siguiente bloque de código para mostrar la cantidad de elementos (el `ItemCount`), pero dicha cantidad es el total de elementos, es decir, el total de los elementos del último nivel, basándome en mi ejemplo dicho total tendría un valor de **6**.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema encontré una interfaz interesante `IMultiValueConverter`. Se implementa la interfaz y a la propiedad `Text` del elemento `TextBlock` (o cualquier otro elemento que soporte `MultiBinding`) se liga la implementación de la interfaz a la propiedad `Converter` de `MultiBinding`.

Basandome en el codigo anterior:

```
<!-- lineas de codigo ignoradas -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
<TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
<!-- lineas de codigo ignoradas -->
```

**Solucion:**

**XAML**
Es necesario crear un recurso para el `UserControl`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <self:ClaseImplentacion x:Key="AliasDeLaClase" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

> Donde `self` es el `namespace` donde se encuentra la clase.

Los `TextBlock` anteriores seran reemplazados por el siguiente:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AliasDeLaClase}">
            <!-- Con esto se pasa el Objeto que pertenece al grupo -->
            <Binding Path="" />
            <!-- Y este se pasa para que se actualice la informacion -->
            <Binding Path="ItemCount" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

*Implementacion de interfaz `IMultiValueConverter`*

```
public class ClaseImplentacion: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            CollectionViewGroup group = values[0] as CollectionViewGroup;

            var depth = GetDepth((string)group.Name);
            var label = "";
            switch (depth)
            {
                case 0://level protocol
                    label += string.Format(group.Items.Count + " Segundo{0} Grupo{0}", group.Items.Count > 1 ? "s" : "");
                    break;
                case 1://level channel
                    label += string.Format(group.Items.Count + " Tercer{0} Grupo{1}", group.Items.Count > 1 ? "os" : "", group.Items.Count > 1 ? "s" : "");
                    break;
                case 2://level pan
                    label += string.Format(values[1] + " Elemento{0}", (int)values[1] > 1 ? "s" : "");
                    break;
            }

            return "   (" + label + ")";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return "";
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //la forma de buscar en que nivel de grupo estoy, en este caso busco palabras clave que determinan la profundidad
    private byte GetDepth(string group)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(".*primer.*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (rgx.Match(group).Length > 0)
            return 0;

        rgx = new Regex(".*segundo.*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (rgx.Match(group).Length > 0)
            return 1;

        rgx = new Regex(".*tercer.*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (rgx.Match(group).Length > 0)
            return 2;

        return 3;//elemento
    }
}
```

> Esta forma tambien se puede utilizar para crear un `Tooltip`.

Espero ayudar con esta pregunta-respuesta.